# Copying int array to Struct int*

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Hi I'm trying to read variables from a file into a int array so I can store them in a Struct array. The numbers get stored correctly into the curLinks array but when I try pass the curLinks array into curNodes.nodes, it doesn't work and when i try print it out (to test) it prints rubbish numbers. Any help would be great.

```
struct nodeInfo* getTopology(FILE *file){
    int totLinks=0;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &nodeCount);
    struct nodeInfo netTopo[nodeCount];

    // How many links does node have
    for (int id=0; id<nodeCount; id++){
        struct nodeInfo curNode;
        curNode.n=id;
        fscanf(file, "%d", &totLinks);
        int curLinks[totLinks];
        for(int i=0; i<totLinks; i++){
            int digit=0;
            fscanf(file, "%d", &digit);
            curLinks[i] = digit;
        }
        curNode.nodes = curLinks;

        netTopo[id] = curNode;
    }
    for (int id=0; id<nodeCount; id++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            printf("%d ", netTopo[id].nodes[j]);
        }
    }

    return netTopo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use pointers and "malloc" to allocate memory from the heap in this case.

Comment: Thanks i changed to the line: int *curLinks = (int*)calloc(totLinks,sizeof(int)); and it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

You define `curLinks` multiple time in the first `for`-loop

```
int curLinks[totLinks];
```

And after you fill that you try to set that in your `nodeinfo` however as soon as the next iteration in the `for`-loop is entered and `curLinks` is filled again, the memory of your previous `curLinks` is out of scope and the memory where you think your read in values should reside can be actually filled with anything - *Undefined Behaviour*

If you tell me the way you define your structs `nodeInfo` I might be able to show you how to do it properly.

e.g.: Assuming you define

```
struct nodeinfo {
    int *nodes;
};
```

Then

```
struct nodeInfo* getTopology(FILE *file)
{
    int id, digit=0, totLinks=0;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &nodeCount);
    struct nodeInfo netTopo[nodeCount];

    // How many links does node have
    for (id=0; id<nodeCount; id++){

        fscanf(file, "%d", &totLinks);

        netTopo[id].nodes = malloc(totLinks * sizeof(int));
        if (netTopo[id].nodes==NULL)
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");

        for(i=0; i<totLinks; i++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &digit);
            netTopo[id].nodes[i] = digit;
        }
    }

    // Free the allocate memory
    for (id=0; id<nodeCount; id++){
         free(netTopo[id].nodes);
    }

    return netTopo;
}
```

Comment: The double for loop is where I'm trying to read what's in the Struct. The input file I'm using to test has max 3 int's hence the j<3 in the loop. it just prints a bunch of randon numbers  1347480480 32767 258941594 1347480480 32767 258941594 1347480480 32767 258941594 1347480480 32767 258941594